# Oracle / OpenJDK compatibility for com.sun.net.httpserver

Tags: java

Are the Oracle Java and OpenJDK implementations for `com.sun.net.httpserver` fully compatibile? Should I expect some problems when I develop on Oracle Java, but ship for OpenJDK (docker)?

Eclipse warns me for using 'restricted' package, which makes me *some* worries, however, Eclipse's warnings are flawed in many domains (maven the most prominent one from my daily life).

Is there a good reason as for current stand (Java 8) for discouraging using of this package in first line? If there is, is it relevant for Oracle vs. OpenJDK or they are fully compatibile for that package?

Comment: There is *a* reason (good or not, you decide). Since that package is considered private, you are not guaranteed that it stays API-compatible in the future or not gets incapsulated in module after Java9 migration. This is the main reason for using any published class - it is guaranteed to stay there and to behave the same. Consider switching to published version of this API.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov the question is, is this 'not guaranteed' a practical or a theoretical issue? If OpenJDK is meant to be fully synchronized, including com.sun packages, it is not. If they are implemented because someone has done extra work, it would be...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That package is part of an exported, JDK-specific API, per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk.httpserver-summary.html . Exported means you can use it. JDK-specific means it's in both OpenJDK and Oracle JDK, but doesn't necessarily have to be in every implementation. Please see http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/179 for details.

Comment: OK this satisfies my needs. We have OpenJDK for docker-able systems, and Oracle JDK for Windows.